# How to Handle this Exception org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest, spring-data-jpa

I implemented *searching* in my backend spring boot project.
When I try to search any keyword it works fine, but when I going to search empty it throws exception. How can handle this Exception?

[postman image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmXl0.png)

[Postman error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNruy.png)

**Code**

**Repository**

```
public interface PostRepo extends JpaRepository<Post, Integer>{
List<Post> findByUser(User user);
List<Post> findByCategory(Category category);
    //seach
List<Post> findByTitleContaining(String title);
}
```

***PostService interface***

```
//search
List<PostDto> searchPosts(String keyword);
```

***PostServiceImpl class***

```
// search
@Override
public List<PostDto> searchPosts(String keyword) {
    List<Post> posts = this.postRepo.findByTitleContaining(keyword);
    List<PostDto> postDtos = posts.stream().map((post) -> this.modelMapper.map(post, PostDto.class)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return postDtos;
}
```

***PostController***

```
//search
@GetMapping("/posts/search/{keywords}")
public ResponseEntity<List<PostDto>> searchPostByTitle(@PathVariable("keywords") String keywords){
    List<PostDto> result = this.postService.searchPosts(keywords);
    return new ResponseEntity<List<PostDto>>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: looks like you have a method in your controller with mapping like `"/posts/{postId}"`, because judging by the stacktrace log handler tries to map `String` *"search"* to an `Integer`

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the stacktrace servlet dispatcher couldn't handle your input value "\r\n" for a variable "search". It happened cuz you are using @PathVariable and servlet everytime is waiting for consistent url. In your situation as a value of variable "search" was used "\r\n" a new line character in Windows.
You can try so set whether this approach `@PathVariable(value="search",required = false)` or as a more preferable, instead of `@PathVariable` use `@RequestParam`